# Angularjs: how change icon when item is clicked

Tags: angularjs

I know that this question has already some answers/solutions but none of them works for me most probably because this is the first time when I'm trying to implement something using Angularjs.

I have a `div` (title) that expands some info when it's clicked and I want to change the icon inside of it when that info is visible...

This is my code:

```
<div class="title" ng-click="view_variables(request)">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
</div>
```

And this is what I tried to do, but not working because the div will not show the expanded info anymore:

```
<div class="title" ng-click="view_variables(request) = !view_variables(request)">
    <i ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right':!view_variables(request), 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left': view_variables(request)}"></i>
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.view_variables = function(req){
    if (!req.enabled_variables && !req.disabled_variables) {
        $http.get('/api/files/' + $scope.file_id + '/requests/' + req.id + '/variables')
        .success(function(data){
            variables = data.data;
            req.enabled_variables = [];
            req.disabled_variables = [];
            for (i=0; i<variables.length; i++) {
                if (variables[i].disabled == true) {
                    req.disabled_variables.push(variables[i]);
                } else {
                    req.enabled_variables.push(variables[i])
                }
            }
        });
    }

    req.show_variables = !req.show_variables;
}
```

Comment: can u just show the controller's code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `view_variables` function doesn't return anything, so it will always be treated as `false`.

You want something like this:

```
<div class="title" ng-click="view_variables(request)">
    <i ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right':!request.show_variables, 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left': request.show_variables}"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was easier than expected :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is what you have going on in the ng-click attribute. By using "view_variables(request) = !view_variables(request)" are you not calling the view_variables function twice? Also, it seems strange to be assigning a value to a function call.

I would just keep ng-click="view_variables(request)" as you had in the first line of code, then have the view_variables function set a boolean somewhere in scope ($scope.data.view_vars) and have that determine ng-class for your i element.

Good luck!

--EDIT: Now that you've put up your controller, req.show_variables looks like a useful candidate

Answer (score 0):

May be Better this way using [ng-show directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow):

```
<div class="title" ng-click="view_variables(request)">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ng-show="!view_variables(request)"></i>
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" ng-show="view_variables(request)"></i>
</div>
```

You could use [ng-if directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) like so:

```
<div class="title" ng-click="view_variables(request)">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ng-if="!view_variables(request)"></i>
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" ng-if="view_variables(request)"></i>
</div>
```

assuming `view_variables(request)` returns true or false... maybe could replace it for `req.show_variables`.

Comment: The `view_variables` function actually does work (toggles `request.show_variables` and conditionally executes an `$http` request), so you don't want to call that in an `ng-if`. The condition for the `ng-if` will get evaluated for every digest loop, so the results will be non-deterministic.

Comment: @Jack A. it's true... then ng-show should be more appropriate?

Comment: Anything you bind to something that gets evaluated during every digest cycle (like `ng-if` or `ng-show`) needs to have a consistent value. For performance, it's better to bind to a variable rather than a function. Function calls are best left for event handlers like `ng-click`, since they only get called when the event is triggered, not every digest cycle.

Comment: I understand now, that's why I suggest to use `req.show_variables`, but I don't know his logic... Yes you are right it will make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function inside ng-class is a bad idea. Why don't you use a flag for it.

eg.
inside controller-

```
$scope.view_variables = function(request){
  //your code

  $scope.isExpanded = !$scope.isExpanded;
};
```

and in html

```
<div class="title" ng-click="view_variables(request)">
    <i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right':!isExpanded, 'glyphicon-chevron-left':isExpanded}"></i>
</div>
```